# How to combine columns with multiple parameters into one column line by line?

Tags: python, pandas

```
for i in range(len('ID')):
    buf = [str(x) for x in LTE_db['robot'][i].split(';')]
    for j in robot_db['robot'][i]:
        try:
            robot_db['final'] = robot_db['ID][i] + '*' + robot_db['Name'][i] + '*' + robot_db['latitude'][i] + '*' + robot_db['longitude'][i] + '*' + buf[j]
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

[image: 1]

[image]

How to convert data from the first table to the second? You need to do it through Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['robot'] = df.data.str.split(', ')
df.explode('robot')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use pandas' `split` method, specifying the comma as your delimiter:

```
df['robot'].str.split(pat = ',', expand = True)
```